# Is there way to a find child element from existing element in Selenium with Java?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

Say, there are multiple elements and their and multiple child elements. I have selected the parent elements and from the code the I want to select the child elements.

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
    This is div 1
    <p>
        This is paragraph 1 under div 1.
    </p>
</div>

<div>
    This is div 2
    <p>
        This is paragraph 2 under div 2.
    </p>
</div>


<div>
    This is div 3
    <p>
        This is paragraph 3 under div 3.
    </p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here lets say I have the xpaths for the divs. Something like
@FindBy(xpath="(//div)[1]")
Webelement div_1;

But I do not define the child element using the Findby tag. I would like to find the child element using the div_1 element in my actual test code itself. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
WebElement div = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='something']");
```

And later you can do:

```
div.findElement(By.xpath("//div"));
```

Or you can use the plural form:

```
 List<WebElement> subDivs = div.findElements(By.tagName("div"));
```

Not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I am looking for this. And this is what I had tried earlier but it did not work. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: Yes, there is - doing it properly :) What do you mean by not working? If you provide exact structure of the dom I can help you to fix the issue.

Comment: As of now, I don't have any such example. I'll be sure to post when I get some thing like that. Thank you.

Comment: No worries when you are ready

Answer (score 3):

If i understood correct you need something like this

```
@FindBy(xpath="(//div)[1]")
WebElement parent;

WebElement child = parent.findElement(By.xpath("./p"));
```